# SCALA: Store the output of select from a dataframe into a 2D array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with 10 columns but I am interested in 2 columns only. I want to store the distinct values from each of the columns into a lists, which I need to use later in the program. Here is what I have tried:

```
         val list1= table.
                         .select(col1)
                         .collect().map(_(0)).toList
         val list2= table.
                         .select(col2)
                         collect().map(_(0)).toList
```

and I can use the `list1` and `list2` later to apply filters on a third dataset.
But as you can see, this involves scanning `table` twice.
Is there a way I can do this without reading the table twice?

Comment: col1 & col2 data type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have less data in the table, 
Try this then -

```scala
 val table = spark.sql("select name, age from values ('bob', 1), ('sam', 2), ('bob', 1) T(name,age)")
    table.show(false)
    table.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----+---+
      * |name|age|
      * +----+---+
      * |bob |1  |
      * |sam |2  |
      * |bob |1  |
      * +----+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- name: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
      */
    val rowArray = table.select($"name", $"age").collect()
    val nameList = rowArray.map(_(0)).toList.distinct
    val ageList = rowArray.map(_(1)).toList.distinct
    println(nameList.mkString(", "))
    println(ageList.mkString(", "))

    /**
      * bob, sam
      * 1, 2
      */

    val row = table.select(
      collect_set($"name").as("name"),
      collect_set($"age").as("age")
    ).head

    val nameSet = row.getAs[Seq[String]]("name")
    val ageSet = row.getAs[Seq[Int]]("age")
    println(nameSet.mkString(", "))
    println(ageSet.mkString(", "))

    /**
      * bob, sam
      * 1, 2
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

Assuming `col1` & `col2` are of type `string`.

```
val list = table.select(
    collect_set($"col1").as("col1"),
    collect_set($"col2").as("col2")
)
.map(c => (c.getAs[Seq[String]](0),c.getAs[Seq[String]](1)))
.collect

val list1 = list.head
val list2 = list.tail
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a function which takes column you want to convert in a sequence and change it to list

val selectColumns = DF.columns.toSeq

```
column_to_list(DF,selectColumns)

def column_to_list(inputdf:DataFrame,col_names:Seq[String])  =
  {
    col_names.map(colName => {
      val col_to_list = inputdf.select(colName).collectAsList()
      println(col_to_list)
    })

  }
```